# Xcode 9.3 now sets CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_WEAK = YES non-ARC ramifications

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, xcode9.3

Xcode 9.3 newly recommends setting CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_WEAK to YES for all Objective-C projects. Can someone explain what this setting will mean for a non-ARC app?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see it allows you to use `weak` properties in non-ARC code and they will be nilled automatically.